# Why does this HR element stop part way across the page?

Tags: html, css

This is a hard one to explain. This fiddle should show what's going on:

https://jsfiddle.net/m6zfvgp1/1/

What I've done is divide a page into a header and content divs. At the bottom of the header I've got an HR element and then I've re-positioned some "buttons" - which are just heavily styled links - so that they sit atop the middle of the HR between the header and content div.

Here's the code:

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 5;
}

#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 4;
}

.hr {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

#buttons .hr {
    margin-top: -16px;
    color: #ddd;
}

#buttons a {
    border: 1px solid #32b8eb;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 4px 24px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
}

<body class="page">
    <div id="header">

        <div id="buttons" style="position: absolute; top: 83px;">
            <a class="" href="/Home/NewJob">New Job</a>
            <a class="active" href="/">Job List</a>
            <div class="hr"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
 </body>
```

However, as you'll see in the fiddle, there's a problem: the HR stops displaying after the rightmost button even though its width is set to 100%. Why?

Comment: why not use the `border-bottom` on the header itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the `div#buttons` is absolutely positioned and it takes the width of the contents. You can make it full width either by:

- `width: 100%`
- `left: 0; right: 0;`

Alternatively, you can use a `border-bottom` on the full width parent element.

```css
#header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 5;
}

#content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 4;
}

.hr {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

#buttons .hr {
  margin-top: -16px;
  color: #ddd;
}

#buttons a {
  border: 1px solid #32b8eb;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 4px 24px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 32px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<body class="page">
  <div id="header">

    <div id="buttons" style="position: absolute; top: 83px;">
      <a class="" href="/Home/NewJob">New Job</a>
      <a class="active" href="/">Job List</a>
      <a class="" href="/Home/Pricing">Pricing</a>
      <div class="hr"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="content">

  </div>
</body>
```

**Check both:**

`width: 100%` Technique:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 5;
}

#content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 4;
}

.hr {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

#buttons .hr {
  margin-top: -16px;
  color: #ddd;
}

#buttons a {
  border: 1px solid #32b8eb;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 4px 24px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 32px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#buttons {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body class="page">
  <div id="header">

    <div id="buttons" style="position: absolute; top: 83px;">
      <a class="" href="/Home/NewJob">New Job</a>
      <a class="active" href="/">Job List</a>
      <a class="" href="/Home/Pricing">Pricing</a>
      <div class="hr"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="content">

  </div>
</body>
```

`left: 0; right: 0;` Technique:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 5;
}

#content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 4;
}

.hr {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

#buttons .hr {
  margin-top: -16px;
  color: #ddd;
}

#buttons a {
  border: 1px solid #32b8eb;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 4px 24px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 32px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#buttons {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body class="page">
  <div id="header">

    <div id="buttons" style="position: absolute; top: 83px;">
      <a class="" href="/Home/NewJob">New Job</a>
      <a class="active" href="/">Job List</a>
      <a class="" href="/Home/Pricing">Pricing</a>
      <div class="hr"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="content">

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using bottom-bottom for the header instead of hr?

```html
<body class="page">
 <div id="header">

  <div id="buttons" style="position: absolute; top: 83px;">
   <a class="" href="/Home/NewJob">New Job</a>
   <a class="active" href="/">Job List</a>
   <a class="" href="/Home/Pricing">Pricing</a>
   <div class="hr"></div>
  </div>
 

 
 </div>
 <div id="content">

 
 </div>
  </body>
  <style>
  html,body{
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
   border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}

#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
 z-index: 4;
}


.hr {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

#buttons .hr {
    margin-top: -16px;
    color: #ddd;
}

#buttons a {
    border: 1px solid #32b8eb;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 4px 24px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 32px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  </style>
```